# Meter Main Wood Shiplap Siding

Tags: electrical, wood, siding, meter

Aesthetic opinions aside, are there any problems with mounting a meter main box directly to vertical shiplap pine siding? Perhaps with blocking behind the sheathing at attachment points. This is not a DIY endeavor—just want to know what to direct my contractor to do, as I've heard varying perspectives.

Answer (score 2):

If it will be kept adequately dry by building structure and/or climate, should be fine. If the siding rots out behind it it's a pain to fix, so a patch of something that won't rot out behind the meter may be useful if the wall tends to get water on it from inadequate eave overhang or prevailing winds, frequent heavy fogs, etc.

In most buildings that's a long-term problem, but for some it might not be a long enough time for it not to be your problem.